# How to create table with links to another table?

Tags: php, tabular

I'm trying to create table of text elements with links to another table. It means if you press one element, another table appears near, if you press another element second table changes to another. How to do it in shortest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery - links are requesting to the another table's id so it triggers the whatever you have scripted i.e. changes a table from display: none to display: block